# PandasのDataFrameのデータの抽出について（Seriesが返されるケースと値が取得できるケースの違い）

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'生物':['しろくま','ねこ','うさぎ','ラッコ','モモンガ','シーサー','オデ','鎧'],
              'HP':[2,50,100,600,60,72,1000,np.nan]})
df1
```

上記のようなdf1から「うさぎ」の「HP」の100という値だけ取得したい場合、感覚的には

```
# 行を指定せずに値を取得しようするとSeriesが取得されてしまう。
a = df1[df1['生物'] =='うさぎ'].loc[:, 'HP']
a
```

こんな感じで「生物」列から「うさぎ」で1行に絞り込んだ値からHP列だけ取り出せば良いように感じるのですが、実際にはSeriesが取得されてしまいます。
値だけを取得したい場合は、以下のように行のインデックスを指定する形にしないと100という値だけを取り出せないですよね。

```
b = df1[df1['生物'] =='うさぎ'].iloc[0,1]
b
```

ルールは分かったのですが、a に代入した値がSeriesになってしまう理由がいまいち納得できません。どうしてなのか、ヒントをいただけないでしょうか。

Comment: 余談になりますが、`df1.loc[df1['生物'] =='うさぎ', 'HP'].values[0]` としてもよいかと。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こんな記事が参考になるでしょう。
[【Python】Pandas loc と ilocの違いとは？　初心者向けにわかりやすく解説](https://aiacademy.jp/media/?p=1551)
[【Python】Pandasメモ：ilocとlocの違い、データの抽出方法](https://kojimanotech.com/2019/08/08/174/)

質問のソースコードに書いてある通り、locやilocの行部分パラメータの指定方法による違いでしょう。

`iloc`でも`[:,1]`と書けばSeriesが返りますし、`loc`で`[2, 'HP']`(`2`は`うさぎ`のIndex値)と書けば一つの値になります。

@metropolis さんのコメントにあるように、`df1.loc[df1['生物'] =='うさぎ', 'HP'].values[0]`とか、あるいは`df1[df1['生物'] =='うさぎ'].values[0][1]`という風に`values`と配列のIndexを使うという手もあります。